# prestashop mail alerts is not working

Tags: email, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using prestashop 1.6 and mail alerts (last version) but it is not working. I guess it´s an issue with the hosting.

What did I do?

- Under Preferences->Store Contacts->Shop I´ve checked the email, the email is correct.
- Advanced Parameters->E-mail->TEST YOUR EMAIL CONFIGURATION->Send a test email, and it worked, but only using SMTP
- I have sent an email via the contact form (as a test customer) to Webmaster and to Customer Service and but neither are received in my mail.
- Made a new purchase as a test customer with a valid email address, but any mail is received in my mail

I also talked with my host company and they say that the test mail is working it must be a problem with prestashop and the module mail alerts!

I don´t know what to do, any help please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a known story... The hosting says the email service works, PrestaShop don't sends e-mail, you think that's the problem is PrestaShop, we say that the problem is the hosting... It's a dog that bites his tail, in this case the 99% of the time is a hosting configuration. Check also if the email sended from the server goes in the spam or is rejected directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
Finally, I fixed following https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/556808-solved-mailalerts-360-does-not-send-mail-to-vendor-seller/